# Code first foreign keys substitution in unit testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, code-first

Let I use code first models with foreign keys like:

```
class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }    

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to use in my biz services queries like:

```
class EmployeeService
{
    ...
    var company = employee.Company; // <-- it is substituted by Entity Framework
    ...
}
```

The question is how can I substitute foreign key navigation properties (like Employee.Company) in my unit tests?

As for me, I found these solutions:

1. Write constructions like employee.CompanyId = 1; employee.Company = _companyRepo.GetById(1).
2. Create constructor like Employee(Company company). It will make the code smaller, but not ideal from my point of view

Anyone knows better solution?